# insert query using Jooq is it possible?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have insert statement in a string value now i want to change that into Jooq and excute the jooq on the DB is it possible ? or am i over expecting  ?

**My Insert Query :**

```
INSERT INTO ANTIQUES (ID,TYPE,NAME,PRICE) VALUES (21, 01, 'Ottoman', 200.00);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. It should be similiar with the following code.

```
create.insertInto(ANTIQUES,
    ANTIQUES.ID, ANTIQUES.TYPE, ANTIQUES.NAME, ANTIQUES.PRICE)
    .values(21, 01, 'Ottoman', 200.00);
```

Please check the tutorial and document.

1. [The INSERT statement](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/)
2. [Tutorial: Getting started with jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/tutorial.php)

Comment: where does `ANTIQUES` come from?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It should be generated. Would you please check the tutorial? http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/

Comment: @longhua That assumes you're using the code generation aspect of jOOQ. I am not, and my guess is that OP is not either. How would this work without the code generation?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some details missing in the above answer, and also on JOOQ's website.
`create.insertInto(Antiques.ANTIQUES,
    Antiques.ANTIQUES.ID, Antiques.ANTIQUES.TYPE,
    Antiques.ANTIQUES.NAME,Antiques.ANTIQUES.PRICE)
    .values(21, 01, 'Ottoman', 200.00).execute();`

1. Here in `Antiques.ANTIQUES`, "Antiques" is the name of the class in tables package and ANTIQUES is the static final object created in the same class for reference.
2. In the same way you will call your column names which are created in the same Antiques class for reference as `Antiques.ANTIQUES.TYPE`.
3. The query will not be effective if the execute method is not applied.